# undefined reference to cv::calibrateCamera

Tags: c++, opencv, libs

I keep having this issue with the calibrateCamera function. I'm using opencv2.4.10 and as far as I can tell all libs and dll's are where they should be.

```
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/calib3d/calib3d.hpp"

...

        vector<Point2f*> objectPoints;
        vector<Point2f*> imagePoints;

        Mat* imgpointertmp;

        for(int i = 0; i<= param.numLights; i++){
            objectPoints.push_back(referimages[i].crn_points);
            imagePoints.push_back(scanimages[i].crn_points);
            imgpointertmp = &referimages[i].image;

        }

        int h = imgpointertmp->rows;
        int w = imgpointertmp->cols;


        vector< Mat> rvecs, tvecs;
        Mat intrinsic_Matrix(3,3, CV_64F);
        Mat distortion_coeffs(8,1, CV_64F);

        cv::calibrateCamera(objectPoints, imagePoints, Size(w, h), intrinsic_Matrix, distortion_coeffs, rvecs, tvecs, 0 );
```

And I keep getting undefined reference to `cv::calibrateCamera(cv::_InputArray const&, cv::*InputArray const&, cv::Size*, cv::_OutputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, int, cv::TermCriteria)'

The dlls I have (eclipse) right now in the program are:

libopencv_calib3d2410.dll
libopencv_core2410.dll
libopencv_highgui2410.dll
libopencv_imgproc2410.dll

What am I missing? I'm using MinGW and g++

Comment: How does you linker command line look like?

Comment: Linking to libopencv_calib3d2410.lib should resolve this error.